# jQuery a more complex toggle() (disable+fadeIn)

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery-effects, jquery

I have a form with a div inside it.
I want to disable the the inputs when "checked" 
and simultaneously fadeIn 0.3 the labels inside div...
else
   enabling the inputs and simultaneously fadeIn 1 the labels...

```
$("#toggleElement").click(function() {
if ($("#toggleElement").is(":checked")) {
     $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').removeAttr('disabled');

     $("#elementsToOperateOn").fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
  } else {
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('checked', false);
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('value', '');

    $("#elementsToOperateOn").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out it works to me as follows

```
function toggleStatus() {
if ($('#toggleElement').is(':checked')) {
     $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#elementsToOperateOn').fadeTo('slow', 1);

} else {
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('checked', false);
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('value', '');
    $('#elementsToOperateOn').fadeTo('slow', 0.4);

 }
```

}